Why is my performance so low with Aeron, 90th percentile less than 5ms throughput is only 2k
I wrote a simple test for Aeron
one client, one server, the client sends data to the server, then the server sends it back and counts the elapsed time.
The final result is much lower than I expected, the following is part of my code and configuration, and some monitoring data
client publication
// client publication
    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 1000)
    private void start() {
        if (!publishTaskEnable) {
            return;
        }

        ConcurrentPublication publication = aeron.addPublication(
                aeronProperties.getClient().getPublication().getChannel(),
                aeronProperties.getClient().getPublication().getStream());
        while (!publication.isConnected()) {
            try {
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
        AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong(0);
        LongStream.range(0, aeronProperties.getRound()).forEach(i -> publish(publication, counter));
    }

    private void publish(Publication publication, AtomicLong counter) {
        UnsafeBuffer buffer = new UnsafeBuffer(BufferUtil.allocateDirectAligned(16, 8));
        long count = counter.incrementAndGet();
        buffer.putLong(0, count);
        publication.offer(buffer, 0, 16);
        startTimeMap.put(count, System.currentTimeMillis());
    }

client subscribe
    @SneakyThrows
    public void receive(String channel, Integer stream) {

        clientPublication.setAeron(Aeron.connect(new Aeron.Context()
                .aeronDirectoryName(aeronProperties.getDirname())
                .idleStrategy(new NoOpIdleStrategy())));
        try (Subscription subscription = clientPublication.getAeron().addSubscription(channel, stream)) {
            IdleStrategy idleStrategy = new BusySpinIdleStrategy();
            FragmentHandler fragmentHandler = this::onMessage;
            while (true) {
                int fragmentsRead = subscription.poll(fragmentHandler, 1000);
                idleStrategy.idle(fragmentsRead);
            }
        }
    }

    @SneakyThrows
    public void onMessage(DirectBuffer buffer, int offset, int length, Header header) {
        long data = buffer.getLong(offset);
        Long startTime = clientPublication.getStartTimeMap().get(data);
        if (startTime == null) {
            return;
        }
        long interval = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
        clientPublication.getTimeList().add(interval);
        clientPublication.getStartTimeMap().remove(data);
    }

Media Driver
java  --add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED \
       -XX:+UseBiasedLocking \
       -XX:BiasedLockingStartupDelay=0 \
       -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions \
       -XX:+UseParallelGC \
       -XX:+TrustFinalNonStaticFields \
       -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions \
       -XX:GuaranteedSafepointInterval=300000 \
       -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true \
       -Daeron.dir=$AERON_DIR \
       -Daeron.threading.mode=DEDICATED \
       -Daeron.conductor.idle.strategy=org.agrona.concurrent.BusySpinIdleStrategy \
       -Daeron.sender.idle.strategy=org.agrona.concurrent.NoOpIdleStrategy \
       -Daeron.receiver.idle.strategy=org.agrona.concurrent.NoOpIdleStrategy \
       -Daeron.term.buffer.length=16M \
       -Daeron.socket.so_sndbuf=2m \
       -Daeron.socket.so_rcvbuf=2m \
       -Daeron.rcv.initial.window.length=2m \
       -Dagrona.disable.bounds.checks=true \
       -Daeron.pre.touch.mapped.memory=true \
       -cp aeron-all-1.44.1.jar io.aeron.driver.MediaDriver

below is some monitor data
iostat -sxz 1
Linux 5.15.0-112-generic (VM-0-2-ubuntu)    06/23/2024  _x86_64_    (8 CPU)

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
          20.43    0.01    5.24    0.13    0.00   74.19

Device             tps      kB/s    rqm/s   await  areq-sz  aqu-sz  %util
loop0             0.02      0.15     0.00    0.98     7.33    0.00   0.00
loop1             0.02      0.15     0.00    1.16     8.05    0.00   0.00
loop2             0.09      0.92     0.00    0.66    10.14    0.00   0.01
loop3             0.02      0.46     0.00    1.04    21.18    0.00   0.00
loop4             0.03      0.47     0.00    1.23    15.56    0.00   0.00
loop5             0.02      0.15     0.00    1.00     8.39    0.00   0.00
loop6             0.81     31.72     0.00    0.22    39.30    0.00   0.27
loop7             0.01      0.01     0.00    0.00     1.36    0.00   0.00
sr0               1.54     54.31     0.00    0.24    35.33    0.00   0.05
vda              15.58    418.32    12.74    1.85    26.85    0.03   1.44


sar -n UDP 1
Linux 5.15.0-112-generic (VM-0-2-ubuntu)    06/23/2024  _x86_64_    (8 CPU)

02:18:57 PM    idgm/s    odgm/s  noport/s idgmerr/s
02:18:58 PM   7436.00    303.00      0.00      0.00
02:18:59 PM  14266.00    482.00      0.00      0.00
02:19:00 PM  18488.00    151.00      0.00      0.00
02:19:01 PM  13230.00    149.00      0.00      0.00
02:19:02 PM  16710.00    153.00      0.00      0.00
02:19:03 PM  15754.00    173.00      0.00      0.00

pidstat -t -r -p 4517
Linux 5.15.0-112-generic (VM-0-2-ubuntu)    06/23/2024  _x86_64_    (8 CPU)

01:47:56 PM   UID      TGID       TID  minflt/s  majflt/s     VSZ     RSS   %MEM  Command
01:47:56 PM  1000      4517         -     18.98      0.01  661284  111056   0.70  aeronmd
01:47:56 PM  1000         -      4517     18.98      0.01  661284  111056   0.70  |__aeronmd
01:47:56 PM  1000         -      4518      0.00      0.00  661284  111056   0.70  |__aeron_executor
01:47:56 PM  1000         -      4519      0.00      0.00  661284  111056   0.70  |__sender
01:47:56 PM  1000         -      4520      0.00      0.00  661284  111056   0.70  |__receiver

Is there something wrong? How can I optimize it?
I keep trying various parameters, but it doesn't work very well.

It is difficult to see why the performance isn't good based on these fractions of code and configuration.
I'm not an Aeron expert, so it could very well be that I'm missing obvious improvements.
What I do see is a lot of litter. E.g. the UnsafeBuffer; and this is made worse because it allocates and frees offheap memory. And I'm not sure about the startTimeMap, but if that is an ordinary Map implementation instead of one that can deal with primitives, then you already have 2 allocations with the following call:
startTimeMap.put(count, System.currentTimeMillis());

Instead of storing the start time for every call in the startTimeMap, if you put the start time in the request and let the server return the data, then when the client receives the response, the startTime can be read from the response. And as a consequence, the whole startTimeMap logic can be removed and you get rid of all the litter (and potentially synchronization, contention etc).
Another problem:
 clientPublication.getTimeList().add(interval);

I'm not sure what the purpose is, but it seems that you are storing every measured latency. I see one potential problem and that is memory issues because the array and number of stored items can become pretty large.
Typically it is better to aggregate the results and not store individual measurements. HDRHistogram is a great tool to store and process latency.
Litter will create a lot of jitter and therefore litter should not be created for normal operations.
Latency with Aeron is typically in the microsecond range, so the System.currentTimeMillis will not provide you enough precision to measure that properly. I would change that to a System.nanotime call.
Before jumping into making random changes, I would run with a profiler and see where the time is spent. The async-profiler is a great tool and you can output JFR files and open them in JMC.
About your topic title: If your p90 is less than 5 ms and you only get 2K requests/second, perhaps the higher percentiles are terrible. Imagine in a single second, there are:

89 calls that take 0.5 ms each
1 call that takes 5 ms
10 calls that take 95.05 ms each

Then the p90 is 5 ms, but since only 100 calls have been made in the 1-second interval, the throughput is just 100 requests/second and not 2000. So you can't calculate the throughput based on the p90; you can only calculate the throughput based on the average latency and the concurrency (Little's Law).
